php-fpm status code 499 (client has closed connection) causes all future php requests to fail and 499 as well
One of my servers keeps having some kind of packet loss issue that occurs randomly. Traffic originating from this problematic server (when there's some kind of weird packet loss issue I haven't figured out how to solve yet) is disrupting future traffic on the target server.  It seems that requests originating from the problem server cause a 499 nginx php-fpm http code on the target server.  Once this happens, all future php requests (from different IPs and networks) to php-fpm also return with a 499 http code on the target server.  I have to restart the php-fpm process on the target server to fix things again until another request comes in from the problematic server and breaks future php requests.
So, how do I prevent this from happening?  I've looked at other questions about nginx and php-fpm in regards to http code 499, but I haven't found much to be of help.
If this condition happens (client has closed connection), I need the php-fpm service to continue serving other requests and keep working, not break all future traffic with 499 codes as well.  What do I need to adjust?
I do have timeouts set similarly to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59713432/nginx-php-fpm-fastcgi-upstream-timed-out/59724098#59724098

Have you checked the logs of php-fpm for clues?
